# Add some content after user login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, authorization, strongloop

Good day.
I created rest api with node.js and strongloop.
Also there is app based on angular.js.
When user login, server send accessToken and it store in cookies.
Every request i send accessToken, and it checks.
So, what is the better way to add some content to Single page app after user login and hide when logout.
Also i created form in angular modal dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to disable some views, accessible by link, like profile view, you could use [`ui router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), create login state and state(s), that can be shown only for logged user using `resolve` option. Please review [this example](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/blob/master/examples/client/app.js), `loginRequired` function usage. You are not required to use `satellizer` (but you could, this lib is really awesome).

If you need to just hide some partial or html snippet, like a "logout" button you can use `ng-if="isAuthenticated()"`.

Hope it helped.